# Symfony 3 - Forms as Services Issue

Tags: symfony

It seems in Symfony 3, if you want to create a form as a service so you can inject services or arguments, you can only do it once.

What I wanted to do was have 2 forms as services that use the same form type class but take different arguments to allow me to set the validation groups to use:

```
services:
  add_page:
    class: BackendContent\Form\PageType
    arguments: [ "add" ]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type }
  edit_page:
    class: BackendContent\Form\PageType
    arguments: [ "edit" ]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type }
```

But when I go and create the form in my controller, all I can do is use the FQCN and not use the alias of the form etc:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createForm(PageType::class);
```

This will only allow me to use one of the service definations.

The only other way around this is creating 2 forms and extending the 1 PageType form so I then have, **AddPageType**, **EditPageType** and **PageType** which I didn't really want to do.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Sorry if this is something I have overlooked but I am unable to find anything in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way around this for me is creating another 2 classes called AddPageType and EditPageType, extending the PageType class and just setting the validation group in each of the Add/Edit classes.

This works fine when using the services now but it is not ideal.

```
services:
   add_page:
     class: BackendContent\Form\AddPageType #this extends the PageType class
     tags:
       - { name: form.type }
   edit_page:
     class: BackendContent\Form\EditPageType #this extends the PageType class
     tags:
       - { name: form.type }
```

Now when I create a form in my controller I can call it like this:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createForm(AddPageType::class);
```

This should from what I have read / been told from others, inject any services etc into my class because it is in the services.

Any further insight on this is very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If your form type differs for "add" and "edit", you should use 2 form types: `AddPageType` and `EditPageType`.

If only some behaviour changed, you should use form type option of your custom types.

It does not make much sense to use the same form type class for 2 different forms, that's why it's no longer possible in Symfony 3.

Comment: Source on why it does not make sense to have one class with multiple form aliases?  Especially given that it was indeed a fairly widely used technique?

Comment: Really? When the form fields are all the exact same? DRY comes to mind. My only difference is telling it what set of validation rules to use. Why would I want the form classes multiple times?

Comment: @coder4show you can configure such things using form options. Even more, if you set the `validation_groups` option of your custom form type, I believe all its childs will inherit it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation groups inside the Form's configureOptions, for example:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Page::class,
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            // if page exists, apply your own logic here
            if ($data->getId()) {
                return ['edit'];
            }

            return ['add'];
        }
    ]);
}
```